# python: breaking a string into substrings using a for loop

Tags: python

i have a string like this:

```
row='saint george 1739 1799 violin concerti g 029 039 050 symphonie concertante for two violins g 024 bertrand cervera in 024 039 christophe guiot in 024 029 and thibault vieux violin soloists orchestre les archets de paris'
```

i have this loop:

```
for n in range (1,int(len(row)/55)+1):
print row[(n-1)*55:n*55]
```

it is working well!!

however, it is cutting the spaces:

```
saint george 1739 1799 violin concerti g 029 039 050 sy
mphonie concertante for two violins g 024 bertrand cerv
era in 024 039 christophe guiot in 024 029 and thibault
```

i do not want it to cut the spaces (however i still want either 55 characters or less per line)

Comment: what do you mean by "cutting the spaces"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import textwrap

row='saint george 1739 1799 violin concerti g 029 039 050 symphonie concertante for two violins g 024 bertrand cervera in 024 039 christophe guiot in 024 029 and thibault vieux violin soloists orchestre les archets de paris'

print(textwrap.fill(row,width=55))
# saint george 1739 1799 violin concerti g 029 039 050
# symphonie concertante for two violins g 024 bertrand
# cervera in 024 039 christophe guiot in 024 029 and
# thibault vieux violin soloists orchestre les archets de
# paris
```

Answer (score 3):

have a look at [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) module.

Comment: Can `textwrap` break within word boundaries?  Erm, wait, that's what the OP wants, I guess..  I just reread the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the clearest way would be

```
for i in range(0, len(row), 55):
    print test[i:i+55]
```

where the third parameter to `range` is the `step` value, i.e. the difference between range elements.

*edit*: just reread your question, and realized that I'm not sure if you want it to break along word boundaries or to just do a hard break at the 55th character of each line.

If you do want it to break along word boundaries, you should check out the [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) module as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886465/python-breaking-a-string-into-substrings-using-a-for-loop/3886499#3886499) by unutbu and SilentGhost.